# redis_store sessions not expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am using the gem redis store for my rails sessions.

My config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
MYAPP::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, key: '_my_app_session',
  :servers =>{
    :host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"],
    :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"],
    :namespace => "MYAPP::WEB",
    :expires_in => 20.minutes
  }
```

Even though I have expires_in 20.minutes in my session_store.rb, my sessions are not getting cleared in my redis server.

Should I do any extra configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a pretty simple fix.

I had used `:expires_in => 20.minutes` within the :servers block.  It should be outside `:servers` block.  So I made my config like this

```
MyAPP::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, key: '_my_app_session',
  :servers =>{
    :host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"],
    :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"],
    :namespace => "MYAPP::WEB"
  },
  :expires_in => 20.minutes
```

Now it works perfectly.